# How to use DACircularProgressView in swift3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I've already used DACircularProgressView [danielamitay/DACircularProgress](https://github.com/danielamitay/DACircularProgress) in Objective C but I don't know how to use DACircularProgressView in swift3?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for Show**

```
progressView = DACircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 140.0, y: 30.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
progressView.roundedCorners = true
progressView.trackTintColor! = UIColor.clear
view.addSubview(progressView)
```

**hide**

```
progressView.removeFromSuperview()
```